# PHP warning on date and time

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, yii

I started working on a specific project using PHP with Yii framework.
When I try to access the project this warning shows up:

> date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

When I search on Google I found that I have to uncomment and change
 `datetime.zone` in `php.ini` file then restart apache server. But still have the same problem.

Please help ...

Comment: So what did you change the `datetime.zone` in `php.ini` to them?

Comment: "In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier." , what timezone did you set ?

Comment: i setted it to `datetime.zone="Asia/Tehran"`
@RiggsFolly

Comment: i setted it to `datetime.zone="Asia/Tehran"`@Vincent

Comment: Are you sure you updated the correct `php.ini` file? There might be more than one file on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php.ini setting should look like:

> date.timezone = "Asia/Tehran"

... then restart Apache (if php is running as CGI, FCGI or Apache module)

If you're using PHP-FPM make sure to restart it:

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Alternatively you can set it in your "index.php":

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran");
```

If you don't see effects of changes made to php.ini, make sure you are editing the file that is used by php. You can check php.ini location used during runtime using this function:

```
<?php
phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in index.php file of yii framework.

```
require_once($yii);

$app = Yii::createWebApplication($config);

Yii::app()->setTimeZone("UTC");

$app->run();
```

Comment: i am using a specific method for all views : `$date =convertGMT2UserTimeZone(date('Y-m-d'),'Y-m-d');`
but when i change it to `$date =  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran");` it worked. but when i tried on my friend's laptop with ubuntu OS it worked without any changes, so i am trying to figure out what is going on !! btw i'm using Mac OSX 10.10
btw thanks for your response and i hope that u can help me :)